# jQuery $.each on Dynamically Added Elements to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

The issue lays in updating a span field with the timestamp value. So if user A posts a message it will create .single-message element insert in dom and have the current timestamp. However the follow code doesn't update when this occurs:

```
setInterval(_updateTimestamps, 15000);

function _updateTimestamps()
{
    $.each($('[data-timestamp]'), function(index, value) {
        var unix = parseInt($(this).attr('data-unix'));

        unix = unix * 1000;

        var now = new Date().getTime();

        var difference = (now - unix) / 1000;

        var result = '';

        var days = Math.floor(difference / (3600 * 24));
        // var weeks = Math.floor(difference / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
        var weeks = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60));
        var hours = Math.floor((difference % (60 * 60 * 24)) / (60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor(((difference % (60 * 60 * 24)) % (60 * 60)) / 60);
        var seconds = Math.floor(((difference % (60 * 60 * 24)) % (60 * 60)) % 60);

        if (days > 0) {
            result = days + 'd';
            $(this).text(result);
            return;
        }
        if (weeks > 0) {
            result = weeks + 'w';
            $(this).text(result);
            return;
        }
        if (hours > 0) {
            result = hours + 'h';
            $(this).text(result);
            return;
        }

        if (minutes > 0) {
            result = minutes + 'm';
            $(this).text(result);
            return;
        }

        if (seconds > 0) {
            result = seconds + 's';
            $(this).text(result);
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

What should I do so the **Dynamically Created DOM elements** are looped and updated?

Comment: The selector is re-evaluated each time the code runs, so if the added elements really do have the `data-timestamp` attribute the code as is will work on them.

Comment: One thing that looks a little fishy is that the jQuery object is based on the attribute `data-timestamp` but the first thing the code does is check `data-unix`.

Comment: So am I correct in thinking that you have a group of DOM elements with a 'data-timestamp' attribute and do those elements also have a data-unix attribute? It doesn’t look like you are ever getting the timestamp of the current element.

Comment: How about using a mutation observer to watch changes to the "childList" property on document.body. This way whenever a new element is added to your document.body your call back gets invoked. In your call back you can check if the added element is a ".single-message" then update the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a setInterval method, I suggest you to use mutation observer to monitor dynamic addition of ".single-message" elements to DOM. Here is the pseudo code.

```
 var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList) {

  for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
   if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
       console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
       if(document.querySelectorAll(".single-message").length ! = messageCount){
        //update all time stamps here.
       }
      }       
    }    
 });

var messageCount = document.querySelectorAll(".single-message").length;
observer.observe(document.body, {childList: true, subtree: true});
```